# Div doesn't have css inside an asp form

Tags: html, css, asp.net, forms, templates

Im trying to get Admin LTE theme inside a asp form but when ever I try to implement it the header gets displaced.

[image]

but if i remove

[image]

```
<body class="skin-blue">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<header class="header">
       <-- Inside the header items are located --> 
</header>

</form>
```

Comment: can you include your css and html for the admin lte too

Comment: i tried to put the body code but its too big and it is not possible to post it here, they wont allow me to, but as far as i got is when i remove the <form> tag the header class will get .body > .header from AdminLTE.css but after putting <form> tag i cant get .header class

Comment: remove the `>` from `.body > .header` or change to `.body > form > .header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css from `body > .header` to `body > form > .header` as `.header` is no longer a direct descendant of `body`

Comment: A descendant that is not a direct descendant is a descendant by marriage. That makes no sense at all in HTML. All HTML descendants are direct. You mean child. (This is why `>` is the *child* combinator and not the direct descendant combinator).

Comment: Hi i have the same issue .tired changing the tag as you told..Did not work ..Should i replace all the instance of body>.header .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the form tag with a style

```
form.whatever{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: nope :( - when i remove the <form> tag the header class will get .body > .header from AdminLTE.css but after putting <form> tag i cant get .header class using firebug